# Ruby on Rails Gets Body Message IMAP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, imap

I am currently developing Mail application where the application can send emails and have inbox.

So, I follow this [guide](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html).

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('mail.example.com')
imap.authenticate('LOGIN', 'joe_user', 'joes_password')
imap.examine('INBOX')
imap.search(["RECENT"]).each do |message_id|
  envelope = imap.fetch(message_id, "ENVELOPE")[0].attr["ENVELOPE"]
  puts "#{envelope.from[0].name}: \t#{envelope.subject}"
end
```

But, I can't get the content of the email. I can't find any variables that keeps the content of the email. Could someone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Following is working for me with gmail as in explained here [imap mail](https://stuff-things.net/2016/03/02/advanced-ruby-imap/)

```
require 'net/imap'

imap = Net::IMAP.new("imap.gmail.com", 993, usessl = true)

  imap.login("username", "password")
  imap.examine('INBOX')
  imap.search(["ALL"]).each do |message_id|
    env = imap.fetch(message_id, "ENVELOPE")[0].attr["ENVELOPE"]
    raw_message = imap.fetch(message_id,'RFC822').first.attr['RFC822']
    puts "#{env.from[0].name}: \t#{env.subject}"
    puts "raw message: #{raw_message}"
  end
```

Comment: It doesn't work on me, I think it's because I am not fetching GMail, but own mail hosting.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that we need to fetch different part with this :

```
<% body = imap.fetch(message_id,'BODY[TEXT]')[0].attr['BODY[TEXT]'] %>
<p><%= body %></p>
```